# Copy Database wizard fails but leaves no text file log

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I've been using the copy database wizard to create a development copy of my database.

Unfortunately, the copy database wizard has repeatedly failed.  I suspect the problem is that the sql server agent service account does not have the necessary permissions.  I can't verify this because the log file isn't actually being saved.  I've tried having it save to the default directory where I know the account running the copy database operations must have permissions and to another location on the server.

Any thoughts about how I can resolve this problem?  The new database is showing up but without any tables...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please use backup / restore. The copy database wizard is a disappointing sack of, well, let's leave it at that.

Comment: Would it be wise to point out that the OP may want to create a COPY_ONLY backup so as not to disrupt the backup sequence?  It sounds like it's going to be a backup from production.  +1, I agree with your answer by the way.

Comment: @Shark yes, I wasn't getting into the details, just suggesting a better overall approach. A recent enough full backup may (and probably should) already exist, so it may not be necessary to take a new, `COPY_ONLY` backup. Scope creep.

Comment: Good point!!  Well said.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Can someone please give some good reasons not to use the Copy Wizard?  Everywhere I look I see anecdotal advice to avoid it but never details as to why! 
If I'm moving medium sized non critical databases outside of normal hours, whats the problem?

Answer (score -1):

As I encountered this problem I suspect it is likely due to an incorrect user id and/or password in the credentials.